# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO, expecting ',' or ';' in /home/content/95/10216895/html/test/call_entry.php on line

Tags: php

I am trying to display values from a table in a dropdown list. but I am hitting the error. Can any help me to solve this?

```
echo "<select name=\"product\">"
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<li>" .$row['product_id']. "</li>";
}
```

Comment: echo "<select name=\"product\">"; this (;) was missed!!!

Answer (score 4):

You're missing a semi-column on the first line.

```
echo "<select name=\"product\">";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
echo "<select name=\"product\">" ;
```

you missed semicolon at end